# Print a singly-linked list backwards, in constant space and linear time

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, linked-list

I heard an interview question:

> "Print a singly-linked list backwards,
>   in constant space and linear time."

My solution was to reverse the linkedlist in place and then print it like that. Is there another solution that is nondestructive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you reverse it again after printing it will no longer be destructive, since the original order is restored.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. However, is that good practice in a real world situation? (Assuming pass by reference)

Comment: Actually you would reverse it first without printing and then print it while you reverse it again.

Comment: @Razor: ish. Normally if you pass something for printing, you'd expect the callee to treat it as unmodifiable. So in languages which care about that sort of thing, either the function needs to (surprisingly) take a non-const parameter or else the function itself must contain const-unsafe code. You'd have to decide whether the benefits are worth the additional risk of writing incorrect code, or whether you'd be better off either making a reversed copy of the list, or using a bidirectional structure instead (e.g. doubly-linked list). If it's a serious enough benefit, anything's good practice ;-)

Comment: It's a terrible idea in real life. You'd almost certainly be using something randomly accessible, like an array, or otherwise not care about O(n) memory overhead.

Answer (score 11):

You've already figured out most of the answer: reverse the linked list in place, and traverse the list back to the beginning to print it. To keep it from being (permanently) destructive, reverse the linked list in place *again* as you're traversing it back to the beginning and printing it.

Note, however, that this only works if you either only have a single thread of execution, or make the whole traversal a critical section so only one thread does it at a time (i.e., a second thread can never play with the list in the middle of the traversal).

Comment: Both the top two answers accurately answer this question. I chose the other one because it was posted earlier. But I voted up this one since it has more details. Too bad SO wont let me accept more than one answer if they are very similar :[

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive call down the linked list chain with a reference to what you wish to write to.  Each node would use the child node's print function while passing the reference before printing itself.

That way each node in the list would pass down, until the last one couldn't and would go straight to the write, then each one back up the chain would write after the last all the way back up to the front.

**Edit**

This actually doesn't fit the specs because of the linear space on stack.  If you had something outside to walk the functions and a method of writing to the front of a string the base logic can still work though.

Comment: But that would use O(n) stack space =/

Comment: That's linear space - the stack counts as space.

Comment: Ah, you're right; forgot to factor in the function, whoops :\  Editing answer to show.

Answer (score 1):

Okay , this could be an interview question , but it is actually a question behind weis algorithms book. The question clearly states that we cannot use recursion (something the interviewer will hide and reveal later on) as recursion will not use constant space, moslty recursion will become a major point of discusion going forward. Solution is reverse print and reverse back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unconventional approach: Change your console to right-to-left reading order and then print the list in normal order. They will appear in backward order. Having to visit the actual data in reverse order doesn't sound like a constraint to the problem.