# Print a linked list backwards in constant space and linear time using recursion

Tags: c++, c, recursion, tail-call-optimization

It seems to me like it should be possible to print a circular linked list backwards in constant space and linear time using recursion and tail-call-optimization. However, I am having difficulty due to trying to print the current element after making the recursive call. By inspecting the disassembly, I see that the function is being called and not jumped to. If I change it to print forwards instead of backwards, the function call is properly eliminated.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205090/print-a-singly-linked-list-backwards-in-constant-space-and-linear-time) related question, however I am specifically interested in solving it using recursion and TCO.

The code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


void bar(struct node *elem, struct node *sentinel)
{
    if (elem->next == sentinel) {
        printf("%d\n", elem->data);
        return;
    }
    bar(elem->next, sentinel), printf("%d\n", elem->data);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node e1, e2;
    e1.data = 1;
    e2.data = 2;
    e1.next = &e2;
    e2.next = &e1;
    bar(&e1, &e1);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiling with

```
    $ g++ -g -O3 -Wa,-alh test.cpp -o test.o
```

update: solved using Joni's answer with slight modifications for a circular list

```
void bar(struct node *curr, struct node *prev, struct node *sentinel,
    int pass)
{
    if (pass == 1) printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    if (pass > 1) return;
    if ((pass == 1) && (curr == sentinel))
        return;

    /* reverse current node */
    struct node *next = curr->next;
    curr->next = prev;

    if (next != sentinel) {
        /* tail call with current pass */
        bar(next, curr, sentinel, pass);
    } else if ((pass == 1) && (next == sentinel)) {
        /* make sure to print the last element */
        bar(next, curr, sentinel, pass);
    } else {
        /* end of list reached, go over list in reverse */
        bar(curr, prev, sentinel, pass+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the "tail" part of "tail call". The optimisation is only possible if the call is the very last thing the function does.

Comment: What's the difference between a function call and a function jump? I have no idea.

Comment: You can't use tail calls to do this, because to print a linked list backwards, you have to do all the work on the way back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To benefit from tail-call optimization you have to reorganize the code. Here's one way to do it:

```
void bar(struct node *curr, struct node *prev, int pass)
{
    if (pass == 1) printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    if (pass > 1) return;

    /* reverse current node */
    struct node *next = curr->next;
    curr->next = prev;

    if (next) {
        /* tail call with current pass */
        bar(next, curr, pass);
    } else {
        /* end of list reached, go over list in reverse */
        bar(curr, NULL, pass+1);
    }
}
```

This function assumes that the end of the list is signaled by `NULL`. The list is traversed in two passes: first to reverse it in-place, second to print the elements and reverse it again. And, as far as I can tell, `gcc -O3` does a tail-call optimization so the algorithm runs in constant space.

To call this function use:

```
bar(&e1, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: great idea. unfortunately it is a bit destructive as it doesn't restore correctly the original state of the list (I know, it wasn't a requirement :)

Comment: That was a bug; fixed.

Answer (score 4):

*Update: this answer is misleading (please downvote it!), it's only true if you cannot modify the data structure.*

It's impossible. Recursion and constant space are contradictory requirements in this task.

I understand you would like to use TCO, but you can't as you have extra work to do *after* the recursive call.

From wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call:

> In computer science, a tail call is a subroutine call that happens
>   inside another procedure as its final action.

Comment: Anything that can be done with tail recursion can be done iteratively, right? (and I'm talking pure iterative here, not "iterative code with a stack structure on the heap")

Comment: @Medinoc: Yes, that's right. I modified the wording slightly as originally it stated that those two terms are always contradictory, which isn't true. And please downvote. Thank you :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: instead of asking for downvotes, you could just delete your answer - it will be no longer displayed and the upvotes/downvotes won't counted. Also, you get the "disciplined" badge :)

Comment: This is not completely wrong; the original recursion didn't have a tail call so TCO didn't apply, and it's not always obvious how to transform a recursion without tail call into recursion with tail call.